# calculate day difference between orders

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, data, sql-studio

I need to calculate the day difference between orders to be able to calculate the next prediction date of this order. I'm now focusing to find the day difference between orders. My assumption was to calculate:
1. The difference between first and last order
2. Calculate total orders and then divide them with the difference between first and last order (so we will have avg days between orders)
3. Add this number to the last order date

I have a problem with calculating the 1 point. I was trying a few queries and none of them worked. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT ClientId, ContactAccepted, OrderValue, OrderDate, OrderId, DateDiff(D, MIN(OrderDate), MAX(OrderDate)) as AverageDaysOrders
  FROM Querytest
  GROUP BY ClientId, ContactAccepted, OrderValue, OrderDate, OrderId


SELECT o3.ClientId, o3.ContactAccepted, o3.OrderValue, o3.OrderId, avg(diff) as AverageDaysOrders
FROM
    (select o1.ClientId,
            o1.ContactAccepted,
            o1.OrderValue,
            o1.OrderId,
            datediff(o1.OrderDate, max(o2.OrderDate), day) as diff
     from Querytest o1
     left join Querytest o2 on o1.ClientId=o2.ClientId and o1.id>o2.id
     group by o1.id, o1.ClientId, o1.ContactAccepted, o1.OrderValue, o1.OrderId) o3
GROUP BY o3.ClientId

select ClientId, ContactAccepted, OrderValue, OrderDate, OrderId , avg(OrderDate - lag_OrderDate) as AverageDaysOrders
from (
    select ClientId, ContactAccepted, OrderValue, OrderDate, OrderId , lag(OrderDate) over (partition by ClientId) as lag_OrderDate
    from  Querytest )
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your data, you may need to break this down into multiple queries, but the average time between orders for a given ClientId would be the (lastOrder-firstOrder)/(numberOfOrders-1). Running this as a single query, you could place that calculation in a subquery and then join to your Querytest table on ClientId, like this:

```
SELECT
  q1.ClientId,
  q1.ContactAccepted,
  q1.OrderValue,
  q1.OrderId,
  DATEADD(day,q2.AverageDays,q1.OrderDate) AS PredictedNextOrder
FROM
  Querytest q1 LEFT JOIN 
  (
    SELECT 
      ClientId,
      FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day,MIN(OrderDate),MAX(OrderDate))/(COUNT(DISTINCT OrderId)-1)) AS AverageDays
    FROM 
      Querytest
    GROUP BY 
      ClientId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT OrderId) > 1
  )q2
    ON q1.ClientId = q2.ClientId
```

For those ClientIds with zero or one orders, you'll find a null returned for PredictedNextOrder.

Answer (score 0):

To get an average between two dates, here is what I would do:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(OrderId) > 0
        THEN CONVERT(decimal(7,2), DATEDIFF(day, MIN(EventDate), MAX(EventDate))) / CONVERT(decimal(7,2), COUNT(OrderId) ) + 1
        ELSE -1
    END AS AvgDaysBetweenOrders

FROM Querytest
```